# View.bounds.height different than expected on NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, bounds

I was wondering if anyone has come across this before. I am using a Navigation controller in my project, and I noticed that when I first push a view controller on it, **view.bounds.height** calculation compensates for the status bar. However, when I closed out of the project and tried the same push again, the **view.bounds.height** calculation now does not compensate for the status bar.

For example, if the actual view.bounds.height without the status bar is 400:

On first load: view.bounds.height = 380 (400 - 20)

On second load: view.bounds.height = 400 (What I want)

Each time, view.bounds.calculation is done in **ViewDidLoad**.

I am using the calculation to set up other views, so I want it to be consistent. Is there anyway I can make sure that the calculation is done **without** compensating for the status bar height?

I thought maybe putting the view calculation code later in the view controller cycle will help, but I've always put view bounds calculations in **ViewDidLoad** without any problem. If this is not good practice, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use viewDidLayoutSubviews. When the bounds change for a view controller’s view, this method is called after the positions and sizes of the subviews have changed. 
So try to move your code in viewDidLayoutSubviews and let me know